# fieldset legend text-align right bug in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, fieldset

is there a way to align a fieldset legend in firefox to the right? I thought it was just my styles but apparently even with an example online the FF fieldset ignores the text-align: right:

http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_fieldset_tag.cfm (works in chrome)

Comment: Which version of Firefox you are using? I viewed the page above in FF4 and text-aligned worked ok.

Comment: mm im using 3.6 on macosx. hmmm that puts out an interesting issue if it works on ff4

Comment: tested on FF 3.6 (portable) on WIN - works with plain `text-align: right;` and `text-align:-moz-right;` however, on Linux FF doest not seem to be displaying elements aligned neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no obvious way to do this in CSS (and in particular, CSS can't really describe legend/fieldset styling at all, so the fact that any of it works is a miracle), but `<legend>` has an attribute named `align` that you can set to `right` like so:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend align="right">My stuff</legend>
</fieldset>
```

to get the behavior you want in Firefox.  I'm surprised some people are seeing it aligned right on that testcase; there are no provisions for aligning a legend right in Gecko except for that align attribute and `direction: rtl` fieldsets.

Comment: The `<legend>` `align` attribute is deprecated in HTML 4.01 and not supported in HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_legend_align.asp

Comment: UAs that implement HTML5 are still required to honor it.  See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#the-fieldset-and-legend-elements

Comment: NOTHING IS WORKING FOR ME! AHH!

Answer (score 3):

The `align` attribute of `legend` has been deprecated since HTML 4.01. However aligning the legend element using `float: left;` and `float: right;` seems to work fairly well across browsers, though you might need to add some margin to the first element after the legend element.

Comment: It's a bit weird in FF, but still probably the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

i am late to answer, but i found this question via google and thought that this might help someone in future

in order to position the legend anyhow you like horizontally, all you have to do is set its `width` property to `100%` and then treat its child elements as if they were inside a one-line block

so, for example, if you want to align the contents to the right, do

```
    label{
      width:100%;
      text-align:right;
    }
```

of course, don't forget to be careful about label's parent width to avoid any misbehavings

Comment: The question is not about labels. If applied to a `<fieldset>` this code would mess  up the fieldset border.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that Firefox supports something like this

```
text-align:-moz-right;
```

Perhaps you could try this out - it might make text-align work in older version of FF.